# Gitleaks detecting leaks after encrypting and pushing files to repo

Tags: git-crypt, gitleaks

Even after encrypting api keys, passwords in project, and pushing code to main branch, Gitleaks is detecting the leaks.
We have used git-crypt to encrypt the files.

Commands used ->
gitleaks detect --report-path gitleaks-report.csv -s [project-dir] -v
git-crypt status -e
git-crypt lock
git-crypt unlock [path to keyfile]

Any suggestions to fix this ?

Tried using git-crypt commands and encrypting the passwords, api keys in order to prevent leaks